# How does one monitor Mule 3 ESB Community Edition with multiple Servers/Mule Agents?

Tags: java, memory-management, esb, mule

Mule 3 seems to be extremely cool however the price tag on their enterprise product just won't just it for us for some clients.

As far as I am aware the community edition of Mule 3 allows you to create as many Mule Servers/Agents that you want and Mule would allow you to deploy to any one or more of such instances.

Within the Enterprise version of Mule 3 there is a very slick web based control panel which not only seems to deal with the monitoring of Mule servers/agents but can also automatically split up jobs either automatically or upon high loads.

I would really appreciate if anyone has found a good open source or inexpensive alternative to this Web based Management Console or any Java based server which would allow the same type of monitoring/control to take place thus replicating some of the Management Consoles capabilities.

Any/all feedback and suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use JMX to monitor Mule instances:

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/JMX+Management

This gives a good insight on what's happening inside of Mule (Mule-specific MBeans) and also the condition of the JVM (standard JVM MBeans).

It also gives some control on the different components of Mule, like the capacity to stop/restart endpoints, etc...

Comment: thanks for your response... quick followup question though... is there any capabilities you integrated which lets you easily create your own admin web interface to monitor current Mules and/or spin up new ones?

Comment: It's easy to create custom web dashboards with the existing internal Mule API, for ex.: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/HTMLDASH. This said, I would recommend using a standard monitoring tool that has its own web interface (like Zabbix). Spinning up new instances is a pretty different subject: it really depends on your environment.

Comment: thanks Dave, excellent info. Regarding the environment question I am kinda flexible there. I essentially would like to find a way to create new integration scripts for clients and when they are done I essentially would like a quick way to spin up a new amazon ec2, rackspace, gogrid or similar instance or attach the integration script to an existing mule server and dedicate resources. Then (if not explained before) I am hoping I can create one dashboard which clients can monitor and one Admin dashboard which provides a monitor dashboard for ALL mule scripts and mule servers. Ideas?

Comment: One option could be to introspect your integration script, locate the monitorable elements and generate the customer/admin dashboard accordingly. This because you can guess what the MBean names will be based on the different names used in your XML configs. As a side note: have you considered Mule iON? That's the perfect platform for deploying Mule configurations.

Comment: could you provide an example of such an integration please?

Comment: I would have to build one... For this I would use XPath to extract the flow names of my configuration then build MBean names out of that. The actual MBean names depend on your Mule instance ID so you'll have to find this out.

Comment: Alternatively, you can decide for a convention for your monitored flow names, enumerate all the MBeans and pickup the ones whose names match your convention.

Comment: @DavidDossot have you ever integrated mules JMX with Nagios?

Comment: No, but with Unicenter TNG. Any tool that can connect over JMX will do.